# Mount Gas Oven Range

Tags: oven

When we had the inspection done on the house we purchased, the inspector told us the oven range (a gas range/oven combo that sits on the ground against the wall) needed to be mounted to the wall.

Neither of us had heard of this, and our realtor suggested we didn't ask for the sellers to do it due to the competitive market for buyers in our city.

I've been trying to research how to do this now that we'll be cooking a turkey in it this Thursday. However, I can't find any info out there on doing this. Do people even do this? How do you go about doing it? It does worry me that if it were to tip, it's hooked up to the gas line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on where you're located; you need to find out what your local codes are.

Generally, you will need to at least install an anti-tip bracket so there's no way the range could fall forward on someone -- a kid climbing on the lowered door, an adult falling on it, whatever. The usual design anchors one of the back feet of the range to the floor, not to the wall -- your range may be set up differently, or your region may have different concerns (earthquake, for example).

If you don't believe your inspector, check with the local building-permits office, who can probably tell you what code requires... or check with a local appliance store or repair shop.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you. The inspector called it a "mount" which is why I wasn't finding any info. Looking for "anti tip" bracket yielded many more results and led me to even the manufacturer's website where they'll ship one out for free if it isn't installed already.